# rrule for repeating monthly on the 31st or closest day

Tags: javascript, rrule

How would you specify a rrule for an event on the 31st day of the month (or 30th, or 29th) that recurs every month, where if the month doesn't have enough days it picks the closest (i.e. for February it would pick the 28th or 29th, for April it would pick the 30th)?

Technically I'm using the [rrule](https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule) javascript library if that's relevant.

To add context, I have a form where the user can specify a start date an recurrence (yearly, monthly, weekly, daily), like for a bill.  If a bill is usually due on the 30th then in February it will be due the 28th (or 29th).

Comment: Take the first of the next month, and go one day back …?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a new extension to `RRULE` called [`RSCALE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7529) to cover that case. Unfortunately it's not widely supported yet. Not sure about the Javascript rrule library you're using, but you should open an issue if it's not the case.

Using the `RSCALE` extension your `RRULE` would look like so:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;RSCALE=GREGORIAN;BYMONTHDAY=31;SKIP=BACKWARD
```

Events having this `RRULE` recur on every 31st each month, unless that day doesn't exist in which case `SKIP=BACKWARD` says "use the previous valid day".

**Edit**

I've just been made aware of another way to express this without `RSCALE`:

#### 31st each month with a fallback to the last valid day in that month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=28,29,30,31;BYSETPOS=-1
```

#### 30th each month with a fall back to the 28th or 29th (in leap years) in February

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=28,29,30;BYSETPOS=-1
```

#### 29th each month with a fall back to the 28th in February in non-leap years

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=28,29;BYSETPOS=-1
```

However, as one can see this is clearly more intuitive with `RSCALE`.

Comment: unfortunately rrule doesn't support RSCALE or SKIP, but this is indeed the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The simplest `RRULE` to get "*the last day of the month*", regardless of whether it falls on the 28th, 29th, 30th, or 31st would be:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=-1
```

Your query sounds like that's what you're after.

I don't know if this is supported by the rrule javascript library you mention, however.

Comment: This is not right. An additional `BYMONTHDAY=28,29,30,31` is needed

Comment: @JuliusŠ. Not sure what you mean by "_an additional_", as [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) section 4.3.10 "Recurrence Rule" explicitly states that keywords such as BYMONTHDAY "_are optional, but MUST NOT occur more than once_". If, instead, you meant `BYMONTHDAY=-1,28,29,30,31` then the result will be _all_ days numbered 28 through the end of the month.

Comment: The rrule javascript library appears to have a [demo](https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule) where possible solutions can be tested. `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=-1` produces the expected result when entered under _RRULE String_ as input.

Comment: This is the better answer. From RFC2445:

"The BYMONTHDAY rule part specifies a COMMA character (ASCII decimal 44) separated list of days of the month. Valid values are 1 to 31 or -31 to -1. For example, -10 represents the tenth to the last day of the month."

Comment: @DanLuba it's not what the OP asked for. `BYMONTHDAY=-1` always recurs on the last day of the month. If you want your event to recur on the 30th of the month, falling back to the last day of February, this approach won't work.

Comment: @Marten I won't quibble, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: @Marten actually, this is precisely what OP asked for, the 31st or closest day if 31st doesn't exist. This is equivalent to asking for the last day in a month. You are asking a different question.

Comment: Maybe it's not the accepted answer because it didn't solve the OP's problem. The OP stated `an event on the 31st day of the month (or 30th, or 29th) that recurs every month …`. That expands to `an event on the 31st day that recurs every month or an event on the 30th day that recurs every month or an event on the 29th that recurs every month …`. That's a reasonable use case and the solution is not necessarily obvious. I agree that this answer is the best one in case of `31st or closest`.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Calendar app sets the rule for an event that repeats every month on the last day as:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA;BYSETPOS=-1
```

it repeats on the last day of every month whether it has 28, 29, 30 or 31 days