# Date is exists in next coming months php

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am new to PHP. I am displaying the monthly events which is starting event from `03/31/2021` on every month, so here is a critical situation come because not every month exists 31 date. So there is some php function available to check this date is exists in next coming months. If exists then display the event on that date otherwise display the last date of the month.

```
$monthly_counter = 0;
$monthly_counter_offset = 0;
$begin = new DateTime($val->start);  // $val->start = '03/31/2021'
$end = new DateTime($val->repeat_end_date); // $val->repeat_end_date= '03/31/2022'
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    foreach ($period as $dt)
        {
            $loop_date = $dt->format('m/d/Y');
            $loop_date_formatted = $dt->format('Y-m-d');

            $due_dates[] = $from_date_times;
            $from_new_date_times = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($from_date_times)));
            $from_date_times = $from_new_date_times;
            $deletedevents2=$val->deletedevents;
            $arrayofdeleted=explode(",",$deletedevents2);
            $originalDate = $from_date_times;
            $newDateforcompare = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
              if (in_array($loop_date_formatted, $arrayofdeleted))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $number_of_days = $val->number_of_days;
                $end_new_date_times = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+'.$number_of_days.' day', strtotime($loop_date)));
                if(date('Y-m-d ', strtotime($val->start))<date('Y-m-d', strtotime($val->ends))) 
                    {
                    $end_new_date_times = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($end_new_date_times)));
                    }

                        $skipcounter = $val->interval_value;
                        if (!empty($skipcounter) || $skipcounter != 1) {
                            $monthly_counter++;
                            $monthly_counter_offset++;
                            if ($monthly_counter == $skipcounter || $monthly_counter_offset == 1) {
                                $monthly_counter = 0;
                            } else {
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else {
                        }


                        $rows[] = array(
                            'id' => $val->id,
                            'title' => $val->title,
                            'description' => $val->calendar_comments,
                            'start' => $loop_date,
                            'end' => $end_new_date_times,
                            'borderColor'=>$val->color,
                            'backgroundColor'=>$val->color_bg,
                            'className'=>'timegridclass',
                            'allDay' => $allday,

                        );
                    }
```

Comment: Rather than creating your own custom recurrence, why not use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events ?

Comment: This is requirements from the client to make custom recurrence

Comment: You can use [checkdate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to verify a date exists.

Comment: To get last day of month `echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('last day of this month'));` or `echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('now + 2 month last day of this month'));`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I am checking this

Comment: @MarkusZeller adding checkdate() function now some work is fine

Comment: @AlexRobbio No I meant why are you writing custom code for this, not why have you got custom recurrence rules. See my answer below for a much simpler and less verbose way of solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using fullCalendar, you can simply specify an event which uses `RRule` to specify the recurrence, rather than using complex PHP code to try and generate it.

e.g.

```
  events: [
    {
      title: "Sales Meeting",
      rrule: "FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=28,29,30,31;BYSETPOS=-1"
    }
  ]
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGByBaV

This will generate an event which repeats on the last day of every month, regardless whether the month is 28, 29, 30 or 31 days long.

Obviously you can use PHP to generate this event object, and enhance it with a custom title, start/end dates etc as per your database contents. But I have shown you the basic approach.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35765662/5947043) for the specific `RRule` string.

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin and https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule

Comment: yes really this is a very easy and simple way to handle but some code is adding by the client so i just follow the code and requirements